# Semicolon or comma in example sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, semicolons

On a resume, which one is correct:

- Worked closely with internal and external stakeholders; for instance, Australian government

Or

- Worked closely with internal and external stakeholders, for instance, Australian government

Should ";" or "," be placed before `for instance`?

Comment: I'd set off the parenthetical with a dash. The semicolon is incorrect, and the comma confuses because of the required use of the other one. / Shouldn't that be '... the Australian Government'?

Comment: SmallChess, don't you think your resume is worth taking to a specialist resume site?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I did because there was no response here.

Comment: I think I'd avoid punctuation. How about "*stakeholders such as the Australian government*"?